# What is the typography term which refers to the usage of bold, italics, and underline styles simultaneously?

Tags: typography

I remember seeing such a word before, but I can't for the life of me remember what it was. I'm googling and having no luck.

The classic web comic [Pokey the Penguin](http://www.yellow5.com/pokey/archive/index135.html) used this technique quite a bit.

Comment: Several terms spring to mind upon viewing the "typography" in Pokey the Penguin. Poor and juvenile seem the most useful.

Comment: I thought I read somewhere that that was the "[lawler weight](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3408)" ;^)

Comment: All styles on the same word or in the same sentence?

Comment: Either one, I suppose. I'm thinking there's a word for the technique of applying all three styles simultaneously.

Comment: I'd call it "too bad" or "too much".  Possibly "unfortunate".

Comment: I don't think there is a legit answer, but I like to call them ***itaboluns***

Comment: There is no such term, nor anything remotely like it.

Even Webster's Dictionary, let alone any relevant text-book, will show that by omission.

Having worked with type for nearly 20 years I promise you, the term for "bold, italics, and underline styles simultaneously" is… however difficult this seems… "bold, italic, underline".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bold and italic and underline are all examples of [typographical emphasis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emphasis_(typography)). Others include (but are not limited to) strikethrough, overlining, changed font and size, capitalisation and letter spacing.

Although bold, italic and underline are the most common, they are not often used in combination, so I don't think there's a special word or phrase for it.

You could refer to it as [***triple emphasis***](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/97113/9001), or if you need precision, stick with [***bold, italic and underline***](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/97113/9001).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the italicized part, but [this source](http://www.blambot.com/articles_grammar.shtml) calls the kind of balloon and bold and underlined words used to indicate screaming dialogue a *burst balloon* (in contrast to a *radio balloon* for more normal dialogue):
[image]

Comment: Very cool info, but not quite what I had in mind. Thanks!

Comment: That simply describes the shape (and meaning) of the *balloon*, not the emphasis on the font.  Note that it even says the balloons are not italicized.

Comment: @Charles, Yep...I think I said that. I just gave the OP a resource to look over.